# C++ serialization from VC6 to Visual Studio 2010 up

Tags: visual-c++, serialization, mfc, visual-c++-6

I am trying to read/open a file that has been serialized with a VC++6 build in a C++ program created in Visual Studio 2013, some attributes/values are not being read or have gone missing somehow.

Please help me understand what is different in the two versions and how I could possible solve it.

It was stored using CArchive as follows:

```
void CCubeShelf::Serialize(CArchive &ar,BOOL bChildren, int iVersion)
{
    if(ar.IsStoring())
    {
        m_dwProperties |= CSHELF_MERCH | CSHELF_MERCH_DEPTH;
        ar << m_dwProperties;
        ar << m_iShelfNum;
        ar << m_fDividerWidth;
        ar << m_fDividerSpacing;

        ar << m_fGrillHeight;
        ar << m_crGrillColor;
        ar << m_fMercHeight;
        ar << m_fMerchDepth;
        ar << m_csFrontPath;
        ar << m_csLeftPath;
        ar << m_csTopPath;
        }
        else
            {
        ar >> m_dwProperties;
        ar >> m_iShelfNum;
        ar >> m_fDividerWidth;
        ar >> m_fDividerSpacing;
        ar >> m_fGrillHeight;
        ar >> m_crGrillColor;
        if( m_dwProperties & CSHELF_MERCH ) ar >> m_fMercHeight;
        if( m_dwProperties & CSHELF_MERCH_DEPTH )
        {
            ar >> m_fMerchDepth;
            ar >> m_csFrontPath;
            ar >> m_csLeftPath;
            ar >> m_csTopPath;
        }
    }

    CCube::Serialize(ar,bChildren,iVersion);
}
```

Comment: This depends entirely on *how* the data was serialised. You'll have to tell us more about that.

Comment: Maybe you serialize CTime objects somewhere else in your code. In VS6 CTime was only 4 bytes but from VS2003 on CTime is 8 bytes long, so if you deserialize a CTime object with VS2013 that has been serialized previously with VS6, you will run into trouble.

Comment: No, unfortunately not the problem. Any other classes I could check?

Comment: It turns out that it was never an issue with the serialization but actually that the = operator is no longer overloaded after upgrading to visual studio, any ideas why?

Comment: Which `= operator` do you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just had a similar problem right now. It has to do with the `bool` type which was not supported on VC6.

I had this class:

```
class CTest
{
  BOOL m_test ;
  ...
}
```

During deserialisation I did this at some point :

```
ar >> m_test ;
m_test = !m_test ;
```

And during serialisation I did this:

```
ar << !m_test ;  // problem was here
```

Reminder: `BOOL` is actually typedefd as `int` on VC6 and on VC2010

As there is no true `bool` type with VC6, the type of `!m_test` is actually int and therefore `ar << !m_test` calls `CArchive::operator<<(int)`.
But on VC2010 the type of `!m_test` is `bool` and therefore `CArchive::operator<<(BYTE)` gets called and you loose 3 bytes in your file. Then next time you deserialize the class, everything that comes after `m_test` is shifted and we read garbage and the program could even crash.

The solution was simply to cast  `!m_test`to `int`.

```
ar << (DWORD)!m_test ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thing to note is: C++ bool is a bit which is '0' or '1' and archived as int.

So when reading from carchive or using binary reader in C# you must read int 32 and do accordingly.

I followed this way:

```
var br= new BinaryReader(targetStream);
....
....
,....
var boolValue= br.ReadInt32()==1;
....
....
....
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.